# QT TreeWidgetItem Creation. Is this a Memory Leak and How should I code this properly?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I am loading a file which I need to create a line for each QT **TreeWidgetItem** in the file . Since I am doing this in a for loop I worry there is a memory leak taking place. I ran Valgrind with this and it doesn't appear to have a memory leak, but I am new at using Valgrind in general. I worry that memory leak exists When the **DisassemblyTreeWidget** is populated I will call

```
DisassemblyTreeWidget->clear();
```

And when I am finished with the program I will delete that object, but I am not sure about the **DisassemblyListItem** which I think might be lost.

Here is the code and I will try to comment in . Feel free to ask questions in the comment .

If this is indeed a memory leak, how then should I program a loop to add items?

```
QTreeWidgetItem *DisassemblyListItem;

void SetDisassemblyWidgetContent(Ui::MainWindow *ui , std::string Address, std::string Mneumonics ,std::string Commment)
{

    const bool __sortingEnabled = ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->isSortingEnabled();
    ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
     //I worry Memory Leak exists here .

    DisassemblyListItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    DisassemblyListItem->setText(2, QApplication::translate("MainWindow", Commment.c_str(), Q_NULLPTR));
    DisassemblyListItem->setText(1, QApplication::translate("MainWindow", Mneumonics.c_str(), Q_NULLPTR));
    DisassemblyListItem->setText(0, QApplication::translate("MainWindow", Address.c_str(), Q_NULLPTR));

    ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->addTopLevelItem(DisassemblyListItem);
    ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled);


}






void GetDisassemblyWidgetContent(Ui::MainWindow *ui)
{
   ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->clear();
   std::string Address    = "";
   std::string Mneumonics = "";
   std::string Comment    = "";

  if( (BinaryType == ArchTypeELFX86 ) ||(BinaryType == ArchTypeELFX86) ){
       ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->header()->resizeSection(0 /*column index*/, 250 /*width*/);
       ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->header()->resizeSection(1 /*column index*/, 380 /*width*/);
  }else{
       ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->header()->resizeSection(0 /*column index*/, 350 /*width*/);
       ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget->header()->resizeSection(1 /*column index*/, 470 /*width*/);
  }


    std::vector<std::string> DisassemblyWidgetJSONContent;
    std::string JsonReturnData = PyEngine_ExecuteCommandWithoutParams("pygdbmi-debugger", "GetTextSection");
    //qInfo() << JsonReturnData.c_str();
    DisassemblyWidgetJSONContent = SplitJsonIntoStringsEx(JsonReturnData);


    for (int i = 0 ; i < DisassemblyWidgetJSONContent.size(); i++)
    {
     auto JsonData = json::parse(DisassemblyWidgetJSONContent[i].c_str() );
      JsonData.at("Address").get_to(Address);
      JsonData.at("Mneumonics").get_to(Mneumonics);
      JsonData.at("Comment").get_to(Comment);
      SetDisassemblyWidgetContent(ui, Address, Mneumonics, Comment);
    }

    //Not sure if this is needed, I will check potom
   DisassemblyWidgetJSONContent.clear(); // Clear Vector
   std::vector<std::string>().swap(DisassemblyWidgetJSONContent);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no memory leak here, because `QTreeWidget` takes ownership of the added items. Qt documentation explicitly states that about `setItemWidget` function. Though ownership issues are not directly addressed in the description of the `addTopLevelItem` function, most probably it works the same.

Anyway to be sure just provide a parent in the constructor of `QTreeWidgetItem`:

```
DisassemblyListItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->DisassemblyTreeWidget);
```

The parent takes ownership of all the children and deletes them automatically on destruction.

Comment: I thought so , but wanted to be sure.